# How to modify the code in TradingView Pine Realize trailing stop loss and profit？

Tags: pine-script

I encountered a problem in the merge code. I want to achieve both trailing stop loss and take profit at the same time. Tradingview can now display ES→EL、EL→XL TRL STP、ES→XS TP, but after I merge the if language, I still can’t display EL→XS TP and ES→XS TRL STP, If you change the code order, only 2 entry and exit methods can be displayed. How should I modify it?

[Modify the detailed view of tradingview]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDiqO.jpg

The entire Pine code：

```
//@version=3
strategy(title="Take profit (% of instrument price)",
     overlay=true, pyramiding=3)

// STEP 1:
// Make inputs that set the take profit % (optional)
longProfitPerc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01

shortProfitPerc = input(title="Short Take Profit (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01

// Configure trail stop level with input options (optional)
longTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Long Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01

shortTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Short Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01

// Calculate moving averages
fastSMA = sma(close, 20)
slowSMA = sma(close, 60)

// Calculate trading conditions
enterLong  = crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)
enterShort = crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA)

// Plot moving averages
plot(series=fastSMA, color=teal)
plot(series=slowSMA, color=orange)

// STEP 2:
// Figure out take profit price
longExitPrice  = 

strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + longProfitPerc)
shortExitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - shortProfitPerc)

// Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? longExitPrice : na,
     color=green, style=circles,
     linewidth=3, title="Long Take Profit")

plot(series=(strategy.position_size < 0) ? shortExitPrice : na,
     color=red, style=circles,
     linewidth=3, title="Short Take Profit")

// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0, shortStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
    max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

shortStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    stopValue = close * (1 + shortTrailPerc)
    min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    999999

// Plot stop loss values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? longStopPrice : na,
     color=fuchsia, style=cross,
     linewidth=2, title="Long Trail Stop")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size < 0) ? shortStopPrice : na,
     color=fuchsia, style=cross,
     linewidth=2, title="Short Trail Stop")

// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false)

// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price and  trail stop loss price

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL TRL STP", stop=longStopPrice)
    strategy.exit(id="XL TP", limit=longExitPrice)
    
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XS TP", limit=shortExitPrice)
    strategy.exit(id="XS TRL STP", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

This is the code that I am going to modify and merge:

```
// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price and  trail stop loss price

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL TRL STP", stop=longStopPrice)
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XS TRL STP", stop=shortStopPrice)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL TP", limit=longExitPrice)
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XS TP", limit=shortExitPrice)
```

Please help me to solve this problem, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price and  trail stop loss price

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL", stop=longStopPrice, limit=longExitPrice)
    
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XS", limit=shortExitPrice, stop=shortStopPrice)
```